# Book where Earth is being divided up into different time periods by aliens

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the name of this book. I read the description maybe 20 years ago. It was about the Earth being divided up into different time periods by aliens. Some parts of the Earth were in the present day, others were in World War 2, etc. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to the side. Please see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info for how to write a good story-identification question.

Comment: Please do try to add more detail to this question, e.g. by looking over the checklists [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394). I've posted an answer which matches your description, but I suspect it won't be the only one; you'll probably need to remember more about the book if you want it to be uniquely identifiable.

Comment: Probably not it, but this actually describes the plot of Doctor Who's [The War Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_Games) pretty accurately.

Comment: Possibly "The Unicorn Girl" by Michael Kurland?  Does it have hippies as the main characters?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another possibility, although only 13 years ago, is [Time's Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%27s_Eye_(novel)) by Stephen Baxter and Arthur C. Clarke, in which, according to the Wikipedia entry:

> The story begins with a series of individuals from different time periods encountering motionless, hovering spheres—and each other—in the region of the Northwest Frontier. Two early hominins, a mother and daughter, are the first. They lack a language, but are referred to in the narration as "Seeker" and "Grasper". Just after encountering a sphere, they are captured by strange creatures in red, later revealed to be British Redcoats.
>
> In the year 2037, a UN peacekeeper helicopter is badly damaged by an RPG. It crashes near Jamrud Fort, which is manned by British soldiers and sepoys from 1885—including the same redcoats who captured Seeker and Grasper, which the British call "man-apes". Also present at the fort are the factor Cecil de Morgan, and two journalist observers, the American Josh White and the Anglo-Indian "Ruddy"—a young and as-yet unknown Rudyard Kipling.

And later

> Bisesa spends all of her time studying the Eye of Marduk, becoming convinced that ancient, intelligent beings are observing them through it, and that she has been able to not only sense their presence, but communicate with them. Neither her friends' concern, nor an expedition with Alexander around the Mediterranean, nor her romantic relationship with Josh, distract her for long. Meanwhile, the British have again used an Eye to support the cage holding Seeker and Grasper, but the Eye begins to compel the "man-apes" to act in unusual ways, as if performing experiments on them.

This latter part more clearly suggests the alien involvement.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds a bit like Fred Hoyle's [October the First is Too Late](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_the_First_Is_Too_Late). I read it many years ago and can't remember to what extent aliens were involved, but it definitely has the Earth being split up into assorted regions each in a different era of history. Wikipedia has this to say (emphasis mine):

> There are more discussions with scientists in the project; they have found that the Sun is beaming an enormous amount of information into space and they wonder what that information is. John, later talking about this with Dick, is interrupted by news that Los Angeles has been destroyed; this is assumed to be so because radio signals from there have ceased. John and Dick join passengers in an aeroplane which is to travel over **the USA; they see no sign of civilization - they guess it is about 1750 there** - and, finding nowhere to land, travel on to Europe. They land **in England; it is the present day there** (although a month later than expected) but **in France it is 1917**, and the British government is trying to stop World War I. John thinks that the Sun was sending information in order to make copies of parts of the world; the odd events during their holiday were when he and Dick were replaced by copies.
>
> John and Dick join an aeroplane excursion: in Russia, they find only a flat glass surface; **Greece is in classical times**. They later realize that the glass surface they found was **the world long after all life was extinct.**

And the explanation for this strange partitioning of the world:

> Dick and John are shown a documentary film, covering the thousands of years since 1966, during which there were several crises where humanity became almost extinct, followed by a re-emerging civilization. The USA which they thought was in 1750 was actually in a period of collapse after one of the crises. The present civilization, aware of this history, no longer want progress.
>
>  Dick and John have to decide soon whether to go back to the England of 1966 or stay in this non-progressing world; they are aware that the present phase, in which parts of the world are in various times, will end, and to stay will mean living permanently in this future world. Dick decides to stay, and John returns. The story concludes as Dick, two years later, considers his new life as a composer in this new civilization.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that this is the book you're thinking of, but someone else might find this question in the future and maybe it will be the one they're after.

The book/episode of [original] Dr. Who [The War Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_Games) features kidnapped soldiers from every major war / time period of Earth re-enacting their respective wars in a simulacrum of their time and place on Earth.

Of course this is for the benefit of powerful aliens who want to find the best soldiers from the most war-like race in the galaxy to make a super army.

This episode was also the introduction to the Time Lords and the one that exiled the Third Doctor (after a forced regeneration) on Earth.